# How to fix "invalid network mode default" when starting docker image

Tags: docker

We have our database running inside a docker image. The VM rebooted for some reason and now I can't start our docker image anymore. It fails with "invalid network mode: default."

```
# docker start 56b
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 56b: invalid network mode: default
FATA[0000] Error: failed to start one or more containers
```

Searching the web informed me I need to change this to "bridge," but for the life of me I can't find out how to make that change.

Please help if anyone knows!!!

Comment: You will need to include a lot more information. How are you trying to run your container? What is the exact command you are trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by editing the hostconfig.json file directly. Problem was, docker service kept overwriting the file because I guess it had it loaded in memory. Stopping the docker service and then editing hostconfig.json allowed me to change the network mode and then was able to get the service started.